# Joomla SH404sef URL adding view=list

Tags: url, joomla-sef-urls

In Joomla sh404sef, I added URL in View/Edit SEF Urls. In the end of the url it takes "careers.html?view=list". How to remove the ?view=list from the url.

When the new meta tags are added in sh404sef for the article or component and the page is viewed as"page view source". It displays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add below line in the code

```
shRemoveFromGETVarsList('view');
```